# Can I use 10A solar controller with one 445 watt panel

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I am wondering if I can use 10A PWM controller with 445 watt or 625 watt solar panel.

Comment: Is the panel's Isc more than 10A? If so ... probably not.

Comment: You can probably find out the maximum current your panel can deliver from the datasheet or product specifications. Most panels in that category can deliver more, so your controller would not be well matched.

Comment: @user_1818839 Short Circuit Current - Isc (A) is 11.47

Answer (score 2):

For about $10 you can get a 30A MPPT Charger, but the customer reviews are pretty sketchy with a fair number of 1's.

Not all PWM controllers are the same in optimizing impedance matching of the PV and autoregulating any chemistry of battery in any condition.

So without more details, it's a definite "unlikely".

625W at 14.2V is only **44 Amps.** ;)
Your charger is probably designed for 12/24V but meaning only 10A MAX.